# getting java.lang.NullPointerException while adding <view> element to my resourse

Tags: android

i'm trying to add a straight line in between two element's using view element like shown below

```
<view
  android:layout_width="2dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/view"

/>
```

but whenever i run application it stops and give me following error

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on
```

a null object reference

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: You want to use uppercase-`V` `<View>`.

Comment: yeah,it worked thanks